# Prove, or disprove, $\int_{1}^{\infty} |f(x)|dx$ converge $\Longrightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)/x=0$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

$f(x)$ is a continuous function in $[1, \infty)$. I know that $\int_{1}^{\infty} |f(x)|dx 
$ converge $\Longrightarrow \int_{1}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ converge, so assuming $f(x)\ge0$ for $x\ge1$, $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)/x$ exists and because $\int_{1}^{\infty}xdx$ doesn't converge:

- if $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)/x=L (L\in \mathbb{R})$ then $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ converge if and only if $\int_{1}^{\infty}xdx$ converge and that is a contradiction
- if $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)/x=\infty$ then if $\int_{1}^{\infty}xdx$ doesn't converge then $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ doesn't converge and that is a contradiction

so I'm left with $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)/x=0$. But what if $\exists x:x\ge1, f(t)<0$ for $t>x$ or $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)/x$ doesn't exists?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. There is a continuous function $f$ such that $f(x)=n$ when $2n-\frac  1 {n^{3}} \leq x \leq 2n+\frac  1 {n^{3}}$ for each $n$ and $f$ is integrable on $[1,\infty)$. Note that $\frac {f(2n)} {2n} \to \frac  1  2$.

Comment: @MartinR I think my answer is now OK.

Comment: But $\int_{2n+1/n^3}^{2n+1-1/n^3} f(x)dx = n(1-2/n^3)$ does not converge to zero. You need “spikes” which become arbitrarily narrow for $x \to \infty$, i.e. $n-1/n^3 \le x \le n+1/n^3$, as I suggested before.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for the corrections. Very stupid of me to  have made $f=n$ on intervals whose lengths do not go to $0$ fast enough.

Comment: by $f(x)=n$ you mean $f(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor$?

Comment: In the specified interval I am defining $f$ to have the consatant value $n$. Howver $f(x)=[x]$ will also work. @CforLinux